# React Native - show data from an API in a <Text>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `fetch()` to get data from an external data and want to display it in my `View`.

`console.log(responseJson)` is displaying data from the API, but `this.state.data` in my `<Text>` is not showing it.

All shown in my app is "Temperatur: C".

Not getting any errors when I'm running it.

Is my `this.state.data` not the correct way to show it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';


class Wether extends Component {
    state = {
       data: ''
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
       fetch('https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp2g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16/lat/58/data.json',{
          method: 'GET'
       })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);

          this.setState({
             data: responseJson
          })
       })
       .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
       });
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <View>
             <Text>
                Temperatur: {this.state.data} C
             </Text>
          </View>
       )
    }
 }
 export default Wether
```

My console.log(responseJson) shows:

```
Object {
       "parameters": Array [
         Object {
           "level": 0,
           "levelType": "hmsl",
           "name": "msl",
           "unit": "hPa",
           "values": Array [
             1005,
           ],
         },
```

Comment: What does `console.log(responseJson);` look like? You can't render objects directly. You can only render strings, components or array of components.

Comment: My responseJson shows: 

'Object {
       "parameters": Array [
        Object {
        "level": 0,
         "levelType": "hmsl",
          "name": "msl",
           "unit": "hPa",
          "values": Array [
             1005,
           ],
 },'

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant information there.

Comment: The result you are expecting is completely wrong. You have to use flatlist to render json data. And as you have seen the response data is in key value manner, how would you expect to show all the json data in a single text? One has to specify a key then its value is get displayed for particular component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have checked your code, seem everything is fine.
Just one thing you should consider is your response JSON Data Object.

> You should not display your **Response JSON-Data** into display in **Text** Component

```
<View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
  <Text>
   Temperatur: { this.state.data.approvedTime } C
  </Text>
</View>
```

> Please recheck your code again, hope it could help.

Comment: i want to show it in input box , is there any way to do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure, in my idea you should not to do that. Because it may mess up your application. However u can try it in the "Value". And i recommend u could using Alert as well.

Comment: I did it with value .issue was that it should be like value={item.remaining.toString()} i was not using toString function here

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize **state** in the constructor, and you can us **this.setState()** everywhere else.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';


class Wether extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        state = {
           data: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
       fetch('https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp2g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16/lat/58/data.json',{
          method: 'GET'
       })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);

          this.setState({
             data: responseJson
          })
       })
       .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
       });
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <View>
             <Text>
                Temperatur: {this.state.data} C
             </Text>
          </View>
       )
    }
 }
 export default Wether
```